# Issue while Loading Listview with AppBar in Metro apps?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, winjs, appbar

Am trying to load listview under AppBarCommand button click.Actually listview is loading and clicking on listview-item will navigating to another page is fine but the problem here is if I click on AppBarCommand twice(or more times) means trying to load listview twice or thrice, its loading fine.After loading listview when we click on listview-item itself application is terminating,its not navigating to other page?Can anyone help me where am doing mistake in my app ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's throwing an exception. Run under the debugger & look at the call stack to find out the error.

Comment: @DominicHopton Am getting the following exception.                        WinRTError: Access is denied.
at Anonymous function (ms-appx://71891a8f-5865-4b97-b2f1-ddb963569520/pages/home/home.js:73:29)
   at CompletePromise_then (ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0.rc/js/base.js:1784:21)
   at Anonymous function (ms-appx://71891a8f-5865-4b97-b2f1-ddb963569520/pages/home/home.js:71:21)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the capabilities of app to see if the resources you are trying to use are indeed enabled from the capabilities.
eg - enable Documents Library if your list view is tied with datasource which is accessing data from documents library.